# Working outside of application context. - FLASK ERROR (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hyy Dev!! I just created a API using Flask in python which takes request and give response

**
Flask app code**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir,'db.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
class STATUS(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    user = db.Column(db.String(100))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean,default=False)
    def __init__(self,user,active):
         self.user = user
         self.active = active
class STATUS_SCHEMA(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ('user','active')
@app.route('/register',methods=['POST'])
def Registration():
    data = request.json['user']
    status = STATUS.query.filter_by(user=data).first()
    if status:
        return jsonify({'message': 'User already registered'})
    else:
        data = STATUS(data,active=True)
        db.session.add(data)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'message' : 'Ok'})
@app.route('/status', methods=['POST'])
def status():
    users = request.json['users']
    status_view = {}
    for user in users:
        status = STATUS.query.filter_by(user=user).first()
        if status:
            status_view[user] = status.active
    return jsonify({'status': status_view})
@app.route('/online', methods=['POST'])
def online():
    name = request.json['name']
    response = request.json['message']
    if response == "Alive":
        status = STATUS.query.filter_by(user=name).first()
        if status:
            status.active = True
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({'message': 'Server Noted'})
        else:
            return jsonify({'message': 'User not registered'})
    else:
        status = STATUS.query.filter_by(user=name).first()
        if status:
            status.active = False
            db.session.commit()
            return jsonify({'message': 'Granted'})
        else:
            return jsonify({'message': 'User not registered'})
def set_all_inactive():
    try:
        STATUS.query.update({STATUS.active: False})
        db.session.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(set_all_inactive, 'interval', seconds=5)
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
    scheduler.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*Client Code*

```
import requests
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
name = input('Enter the name : ')
sender = input('sender : ')
def NEWUSER():
    url_req = url + '/register'
    response = requests.post(url=url_req,json=({'user':name}))
    print(response.json())
def UPDATE():
    url_req = url + '/online'
    response = requests.post(url=url_req, json=({'name':name,'message':"Alive"} ))
    print(response.json())
def GETUSER():
    url_req = url + '/status'
    users = [sender]
    response = requests.post(url=url_req,json=({'users':users}))
    print(response.json())
NEWUSER()
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(GETUSER, 'interval', seconds=8)
scheduler.add_job(UPDATE, 'interval', seconds=6)
scheduler.start()
```

error

'''
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Apr/2023 23:36:53] "POST /online HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Job "set_all_inactive (trigger: interval[0:00:05], next run at: 2023-04-15 23:36:59 IST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Python\Flask_RestAPI\active.py", line 72, in set_all_inactive
STATUS.query.update({STATUS.active: False})
^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\model.py", line 31, in **get**
cls, session=cls.**fsa**.session()  # type: ignore[arg-type]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\scoping.py", line 218, in **call**
sess = self.registry()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util_collections.py", line 639, in **call**
key = self.scopefunc()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\session.py", line 102, in _app_ctx_id
return id(app_ctx._get_current_object())  # type: ignore[attr-defined]
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\k\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
'''

Please Help me with my problem i tried with chatGPT too but not working. Thanks in advance..

i tried using app.app_context() but not worked. I'm expecting that after each 10 sec the data in table ACTIVE has active to set False. I'm trying to establish a heartbeat mechanism which is followed to server to check whether the client is online or not...